# If $K\subset{\mathbb{R}}$ closed and bounded, then K compact Proof (without covers)

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have already proved the reverse (Heine-Borel Theorem) by use of the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem, but, reading several proofs of this forward direction, am yet to come across a (short) proof which shows this without the need for open covers - note, here I define a compact set to be a subset $K\subset{\mathbb{R}}$ such that every sequence in $K$ has a subsequence that converges to a limit that is also in $K$ Could someone please show thus this forwards direction (closed and bounded, then compact) without resorting to open covers (not for lack of knowledge, but as covers appear on the next page of this theorem in the book I'm studying).

Comment: To be clear, you want a proof of the fact that closed and bounded implies compact, right?

Comment: @GuidoA. A. Yes (have now edited to be more clear)

Comment: A family  $F$ of sets  has the Finite Intersection Property (F.I.P.) iff  $\cap G\ne \emptyset$ for every non-empty finite $G\subset F.$... An equivalent to " the space $K$ is compact" is that if $F$ is any non-empty family of closed subsets of $K$ and if $F$ has the F.I.P. then $\cap F\ne \emptyset.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_n)_{n \geq 1} \subseteq K$. Since $K$ is bounded, so is this sequence. By Bolzano-Weierstraß, there exists a convergent (in the whole space) subsequence $(x_{n_j})_{j \geq 1}$. Since $K$ is closed, this subsequence converges in $K$.

Comment: Thank you for yours (and the above) answers - case closed. Don't know why I didn't realise this myself earlier!

Answer (score 3):

Let $ x_n $ be a sequence in $ K $, which is a closed and bounded subset of $ \mathbb R $. It is a well known property of $ \mathbb R $ that any sequence has a monotone subsequence, so let $ x_{k_n} $ be a monotone subsequence. Then $ x_{k_n} $ is a monotone, bounded (as $ K $ is bounded) sequence in $ \mathbb R $. By the least upper bound property of $ \mathbb R $, $ x_{k_n} $ converges to some $ x \in \mathbb R $. Then as $ K $ is closed and $ x_n $ is a sequence in $ K $, $ x \in K $, which shows compactness of $ K $.